# R arules, mine only rules from specific column

Tags: r, apriori, arules

I would like to mine specific rhs rules. There is an example in the documentation which demonstrates that this is possible, but only for a specific case (as we see below). First an data set to illustrate my problem:

```
input <- matrix( c( rep(10001,6) , rep(10002,3) , rep(10003,3), 100001,100002,100003,100004,100005,100006,100002,100003,100007,100002,100003,100008,rep('a',6),rep('b',6)), ncol=3)
colnames(input) <- c(letters[1:3])
input <- as.data.frame(input)
```

Now i can create rules:

```
 r <- apriori(input)
```

To see the rules:

```
inspect(r)
```

I would like to only mine rules that have b=... on the rhs. For specific values this can be done by adding:

```
appearance = list(rhs = c("b=100001", "b=100002"),default="lhs")
```

to the apriori command. I will also have to adjust the confidence if i want to find them ofcourse. The problem lies in the number of elements in column b. I can manualy type all the elements in the "b=....." format in this example, but I can't in my own data.

I tried to get the values of b using unique() and then giving that to the rhs, but it will generate an error because i give values like: "100001" "100002" instead of "b=100001" "b=100002".

Is there a was to only get rhs rules from a specific column?

If not, is there an easy way to generate 'want' from 'current?

```
current <- c("100001", "100002", "100003", "100004", "100005", "100006", "100007", "100008")
want    <- c("b=100001", "b=100002", "b=100003", "b=100004", "b=100005", "b=100006", "b=100007", "b=100008")
```

Somewhat related is this question: [Creating specific rules with arules in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131792/creating-specific-rules-with-arules-in-r)
But that has the same problem for me, only a different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `subset`:

```
r <- apriori(input, parameter = list(support = 0.1, confidence = 0.1))
inspect( subset( r, subset = rhs %pin% "b=" ) )
#   lhs      rhs          support confidence     lift
# 1 {}    => {b=100002} 0.2500000  0.2500000 1.000000
# 2 {}    => {b=100003} 0.2500000  0.2500000 1.000000
# 3 {c=b} => {b=100002} 0.1666667  0.3333333 1.333333
# 4 {c=b} => {b=100003} 0.1666667  0.3333333 1.333333
```

For you second question, you can use `paste`:

```
paste0( "b=", current )
# [1] "b=100001" "b=100002" "b=100003" "b=100004" "b=100005" "b=100006" "b=100007"
# [8] "b=100008"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `arules` [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/arules.pdf) now has an example that does exactly what you want:

```
bItems <- grep("^b=", itemLabels(input), value = TRUE)
rules <- apriori(input, parameter = list(support = 0.1, confidence = 0.1),
 appearance = list(rhs = bItems))
```

I haven't actually tested this with your example code (the `arules` documentation example uses a `transactions` object, not a `data.frame`), but grep-ing those column labels should work out.