# Constraining association rules by multiple strings

Tags: r, rstudio, apriori, arules

I was wondering if anyone knows how to constrain the left and right hand sides in apriori (arules) by pointing to a .csv containing the constraints.

[A very similar question was asked and answered in this post for anyone else struggling with something similar.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926131/how-to-get-items-for-both-lhs-and-rhs-for-only-specific-columns-in-arules)

```
rules_sales <- apriori(sales, 
                       parameter=list(support=0.001, confidence=0.5, minlen=2, maxlen=2), 
                       appearance=list(lhs=c("HouseOwnerFlag=0", "HouseOwnerFlag=1"), 
                       rhs=paste0("Product=", unique(sales$Product)), default="none"))
```

However I have a fairly substantial list of constraints to apply and am trying to avoid typing or copying and pasting directly into R.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Why not write you code in an editor or IDE than allows an #include call? Then just `source` the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verena Haunschmid provides the answer to this in **Solution 2:** of their post:

[How to get items for both LHS and RHS for only specific columns in arules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926131/how-to-get-items-for-both-lhs-and-rhs-for-only-specific-columns-in-arules?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered.