# Aprori in R, how to return products with specific string in RHS

Tags: r, apriori, arules

I want to return RHS rules that have any numbers, or that contain specific string like ".part". When I run the code below I get an error.

Any ideas on how to get the RHS to return all items containing a specified string or any numeric digits?

```
library("arules")

basket_rules <- apriori(ttk, parameter = list(sup = 0.0008, conf = 0.10, target="rules"), appearance = list(rhs = \\d, default = "lhs"))

# Error: unexpected input in:  
# "basket_rules <- apriori(ttk, parameter = list(sup = 0.0008, conf = 0.10, target="rules"), appearance = list(rhs = \"
```

any thoughts on how to get around this error is really appreciated!

Comment: you might find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926131/how-to-get-items-for-both-lhs-and-rhs-for-only-specific-columns-in-arules?rq=1

Comment: @MFR Certainly helps, Not exactly what I was hoping for but it may be close enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Appearance does not support regular expressions, you need to supply a vector of actual item labels (see `? APappearance`). You could do something like this:

```
use_for_rhs <- grep("\\d", itemLabels(ttk), value = TRUE)
basket_rules <- apriori(ttk, 
    parameter = list(sup = 0.0008, conf = 0.10, target="rules"), 
    appearance = list(rhs = use_for_rhs, default = "lhs"))
```